# Neo4j Cypher could not match string parenthesis

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo4J database containing the Employee data. Every employee contains a name and department.
Some of the department names contain parenthesis in the string literal in the db.

Eg.

```
Employee { name: "abcd", department: "Human Resources (Recruitment)" }
```

I need to search employee having department exact matched with the User search string. Meaning if someone search with "Human Resources (Recruitment)" then I should get above employee's record in the search result. If the search is not exact match I don't need the employee record in the result.

I tried following cypher query but its not working.

```
Match (e: Employee) where e.department = "Human Resources (Recruitment)" return e
```

If I replace = with CONTAINS it works fine, but I need exact match and not partial one. I have already tried following things but nothing seems to work.

```
Match (e: Employee) where e.department = '"Human Resources (Recruitment)'" return e

Match (e: Employee) where e.department = "Human Resources \(Recruitment\)" return e

Match (e: Employee) where e.department = "`Human Resources (Recruitment)`" return e
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It should work out of the box. Do you have an index/constraint on that value?

Comment: Your first query is valid, it should work. I just created the same node and your query returns the valid result. Are you sure there is no garbage in the department field like invisible characters, space characters or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly fine:

I ran these and all worked.

```
create (:Employee { name: "abcd", department: "Human Resources (Recruitment)" });
MATCH (n:Employee) RETURN n LIMIT 25;
match (e:Employee { department: "Human Resources (Recruitment)" }) return *;
match (e:Employee) where e.department: "Human Resources (Recruitment)" return *;
create index on :Employee(department);
match (e:Employee) where e.department = "Human Resources (Recruitment)" return *
```